# Export and import to Azure Devops existing Azure function in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, function, azure-devops

I have a Visual Studio function. It's already published to my Azure Devops account. Is there a way to export this Visual Studio function to another devops without publishing to that server? I am new to Azure Devops. If anyone has an idea, please let me know.

Comment: What did you publish it to? I assumt you published it to a Git repo? Just use any number of online giudes that show you how to transfer code between Git repos. This usually requires 1. Cloning locally; 2.pushing to another repo.

Comment: I already publish visual studio function to azure. Assume that this function need to publish another azure portal. So I need to know is there are way to do it without change my existing publish details

Comment: Have you published directly to Azure (where it is running)? I don't understand where DevOps comes into this - what actual asset do you have in DevOps. It soudns like you have published directly to Azure and now you are you asking how to do CI/CD for an Azure functions. Can you clarify? Do you have anything in Git? Do you have a running Azure function?

Comment: yes you are right. i just investigate it. actually i need  how to do CI/CD for an Azure functions. I have no idea before that.

Comment: This was the first slide when I googled it: https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/azurefunctions/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks